# How to enable WiFi on Dell Latitude E6330 running kali Linux?

Tags: linux, drivers, kali-linux, wifi-driver

I recently received a Dell Latitude E6330, installed Kali Linux on it, and found that the WiFi was not working. The computer I am writing this on has Kali, and the WiFi is working fine(Obviously). I have tried: Reinstalling Kali Linux, Flipping the switch back and forth, Configure the network manually, Search for drivers(None found)

Please help me. If you have any questions, comment.

EDIT:

output of below command:
Subsystem: Dll BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n [1028:0014]
Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge

Comment: Can you find out which WLAN card the computer uses? Would you be averse to changing it to one that you can confirm has drivers under your version of Kali Linux?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command in order to identify the WiFi chipset. With that information I can give you an exact answer, start a comment with @ChanganAuto so I'll be notified of your edit. Otherwise follow the generic answer below.

Comment: Obligatory reading: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me . If you're using Kali you're supposed to know how to solve it, honestly. You should consider using a proper desktop Linux. Kali has a very narrow usages span and shouldn't be used as a daily driver.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Hello. I have added the output.

Comment: With a temporary internet connection (LAN, USB tethering, etc.) can you try installing `sudo apt install broadcom-sta-dkms` , reboot and test? If it works I can post as an answer.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, I attempted to install it but there was no package found. I was connected to ethernet at the time.

Comment: If so you should check the repositories, very likely you haven't all of them enabled.

Answer (score 1):

There are specific drivers for each wireless card. According to [Dell's specs](https://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/Dell_Latitude_E6330_spec-sheet.pdf), the E6330 *might* have an Intel® Centrino® Advanced-N 6205, Intel® Centrino® Advanced-N + WiMAX 6250 3 , Intel® Centrino® Ultimate-N 6300, Dell Wireless™ 1504 (802.11g/n 1x1), or Dell Wireless 1540 (802.11n 2x2).

- Check your PC for the WiFi device installed.
- Look online for a Linux driver for that card.
- If no driver is available for Kali Linux, or it's too difficult to install, get a Linux-compatible WiFi USB dongle for ~US$10, [such as this TP-Link device](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008IFXQFU) or [this by EDUP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0827LG8L2) (**N.B.** I've not tried either on Kali Linux).

BTW, Kali is one of the more difficult distros to configure. You might consider another, such as Ubuntu, which is usually *quite* easy to install.

Comment: The Intel ones use open-source drivers therefore supported at the kernel level (Kali uses the same kernel branches as the contemporary Debian it's based on) so those shouldn't be a problem. Now, those "Dell Wireless" are surely rebranded/relabeled from something else. My bet is on some Broacom chips.

Comment: Yeap, Google pretty much confirms either "Dell Wireless" are actually rebranded Broadcoms. The OP must have one of those otherwise it would just work (Intel). Broadcom chips always need proprietary drivers. This should work the same in any Debian based distro: https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Comment: On eBay, there are E6330 cards for sale with Broadcom label, for what it's worth. e.g., BRCM1050 at https://www.ebay.com/itm/224711410862?epid=1700635042&hash=item3451d804ae:g:2P0AAOSwW~NhoIEy , confirming @ChanganAuto comment